# How to read data from table and assign sequence number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sequence, alter-table

I am trying to create add a column to a table but i'm stuck trying to figure out a way to assign sequence number to this column.

Here is what I have:

```
ID           C_Seq_No        D_Seq_No         Type
123              1             NULL            02
123              1             NULL            04
123              1             NULL            06
123              2             NULL            03
123              2             NULL            05
123              2             NULL            07
```

This is what I want in my table:

```
ID           C_Seq_No        D_Seq_No         Type
123              1             1               02
123              1             2               04
123              1             3               06
123              2             1               03
123              2             2               05
123              2             3               07
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: do you have to `update` the table?

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by id, c_seq_no order by type) as d_seq_no
from t;
```

If you actually want an update, you can use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, c_seq_no order by type) as new_d_seq_no
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set d_seq_no = new_d_seq_no;
```